# Remove an object from a JSON array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

From table rows in my PostgreSQL 12.8 database, I am trying to remove an object from an array, but instead it is deleting whole array of objects from the table.

`settings` column holds below array of objects:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 100,
            "name": "testOne",
            "settings": "settingOne"
        },
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": testTwo,
            "settings": "settingTwo"
        },
]
```

I have three rows in the `users` table with the column `settings` of type `jsonb` that holds an array of objects.

I want to delete the object with id = 101 for all users. I tried the below query:

```
update users
set settings = 
    jsonb_set(settings , '{settings}', (settings->'id') - (select distinct position-1 from users, jsonb_array_elements(settings) 
    with ordinality arr(elem, position) WHERE elem->>'id' = '101')::int)
```

By executing the above query it is deleting everything from the settings. How can I modify the above query in order to achieve the below result?

```
   [
            {
                "id": 100,
                "name": "testOne"
                "settings": "settingOne"
            }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```sql
UPDATE users u
SET    settings = (SELECT jsonb_agg(a.elem)
                   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(u.settings) AS a(elem)
                   WHERE  (a.elem ->> 'id' = '101') IS NOT TRUE)
WHERE  u.settings @> '[{"id":101}]';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KwjmTKNT)

The added outer `WHERE` clause makes sure only rows are updated that actually change. You may have additional filters ...

This removes *all* objects from the array that have `"id": 101`. (There might be more than one.)

To only remove the first match:

```sql
UPDATE users u
SET    settings = u.settings
                - (SELECT a.ord::int-1
                   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(u.settings) WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, ord)
                   WHERE  a.elem ->> 'id' = '101'
                   LIMIT  1)
WHERE  u.settings @> '[{"id":101}]';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_Up3d0j5)

Notably, do *not* repeat the table name in the correlated subquery, that would be expensive bloat - and require addtitional filters to link back to the updated table.

`-1` is there because Postgres ordinality numbers start with 1 while JSON array elements start with 0.

About `WITH ORDINALITY`:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: Thank you for very well explanation. I have one question regarding the second query. What do you mean by "to only remove the first match" you mean in case of duplicated id's in the json?

Comment: @JN_newbie Yes, observe the effect in the two fifdles I added.

Comment: Thank you Erwin I have just performed the tests and understand the concept behind as what you have mentioned in your answer. Thank you for the detail answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [operator -](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) only, no need to use `jsonb_set`.

This is an optimized solution since it call `where` only once. if no data found it will return the `settings length` this way we will be sure nothing will be removed.

```
update users
set settings = 
    settings  - (
    select coalesce(
       (select position::int-1 as index
        from jsonb_array_elements(settings) 
        with ordinality arr(elem, position) 
        WHERE elem->>'id' = '100'
        LIMIT 1
       ), 
       jsonb_array_length(settings))
   )
```

The operator `-` Delete the array element with specified index (Negative integers count from the end).

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/_uAHpxjm)

Comment: @JN_newbie: Much is wrong with this answer. 1.) It updates all rows, including those that don't change. Very expensive, without need. 2.) The subquery is uncorrelated, which makes it incorrect, on top of *very* expensive. 3.)  The explanation does not apply. Negative integers have nothing to do with this query.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I do agree with with the statement negative integers have nothing to do with this query. I just realised after performing some tests it will update all the rows as Outer where clause is not provided.

Comment: @JN_newbie Even more importantly, repeating `users` in the subquery effectiely makes it uncorrelated and completely breaks the query.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinBrandstetter my query wasn't correct when there is no element found the whole json get removed, the third point I think you both misunderstand, the operator `-` accept negative and positive indexes, this is just an info how this operator can be used

Comment: @SelVazi: This fixes most problems. But it's much better to update only rows that actally change. Then you also don't need coalesce.